# How to copy license from host package

Tags: c++, jinja2, conda-build, conda-forge

When compiling software that makes use of a header-only library, licensing can require a copy of the library's license to be distributed with the compiled software. Moreover, Conda Forge is explicit (see [PR template](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/blob/main/.github/pull_request_template.md)) that packages must include the original licenses of statically-linked dependencies, which is *ipso facto* the case for header-only libraries. However, I am unable to find documentation on how to resolve the license file for `host`-level packages.

**How does one specify in a `meta.yaml` recipe to copy the license(s) from a particular package?**

### Minimal Example

Here's a minimal example using the `tsl_robin_map` header-only library. I know that [the `tsl_robin_map` package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tsl_robin_map/files) tarball has the license in `info/licenses/LICENSE`. However, I don't know how to specify that path in the recipe.

**meta.yaml**

```yaml
package:
  name: hello-robin
  version: 0.1

source:
  path: .

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
  host:
    - tsl_robin_map

test:
  commands:
    - hello-robin

# about:
#   license_file:   
#     - <path_to_tsl_robin_map>/info/licenses/LICENSE  # <- how should this be specified?
```

**hello.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tsl/robin_map.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, Robin!";
}
```

**build.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
${CXX} ${CPPFLAGS} -o hello-robin hello.cpp
mkdir -p ${PREFIX}/bin
mv hello-robin ${PREFIX}/bin/hello-robin
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no such way in conda-build yet. It's a good feature to have.
Can you open an issue in conda/conda-build?